# What do we refer to when we say algebraic structure?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A set of all the operations on set $A$ is called an algebraic structure on set $A$?

Can anybody explain this statement to me.

What I understand from this is that, consider a set $\mathbb{N} $ then,

Algebraic structure on set $\mathbb{N}$ is the collection of all operators on $\mathbb{N}$ meaning,

Algebraic Structure $= \{+, \times, \cdots \} $?

I watched a couple of videos on YouTube about algebraic structure. Some of them seem to give some other different definitions of Algebraic Structures.

Can anyone explain what does it **"precisely"** refer to? The operator? Set of operators? The set $A$ itself?

Comment: This has been answered here already. For some links, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282110/why-algebraic-structures).

Comment: @DietrichBurde idk it's about why algebraic structures are used. My question is what exactly are Algebraic Structures?

Comment: This is also answered there. In particular, it says "a class of algebraic structures is called a *variety of algebras* if it can be defined using only equations (like $x\cdot (y\cdot z) = (x\cdot y) \cdot z$). Examples of varieties are groups, rings, modules, boolean algebras... Varieties are the core topic of study in the field of universal algebra".  Did you have a look at other related links there?

Comment: So one possible answer to your question (see title) "What do we refer to when we say algebraic structure?" is *varieties of algebras*.